# Formatting microSD card error

Tags: sd-card

I'm trying to format a SanDisk 16GB microSD card but when I do I keep getting the following message:

> One or more partitions are busy on /dev/mmcblk0

How do I correct this so that I can properly format the card? I've tried formatting it with GParted but it never makes it past the second step.

Comment: you can see mounted partitions with the 'mount' comand. And you can unmount one with the umount command in a terminal. or right-click on partition in gparted and choose unmount

Answer (score 1):

try umount it first.
Use the new utility that comes with ubuntu , its name is disk utility or something like this.

or try open a terminal and do

```
sudo mkfs /dev/mmcblk0 -t ext3
```

or `-t vfat`
if you want to use it on windows